# Set default color for a specific widget in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter, layout, colors, flutter-layout

Is it possible to specify in flutter a color that will be used as default one in a single widget?

For example, I have this situation:

```
Widget _widget1 = Scaffold(
    body: Center(
        child: new Container(
            width: 300.0,
            height: 300.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange, //TODO set orange as default for BoxDecoration
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
            )
        )
    )
);

Widget _widget2 = Scaffold(
    body: Center(
        child: new Container(
            width: 120.0,
            height: 150.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange, //TODO set orange as default for BoxDecoration
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            )
        )
    )
);
```

and I want to not specify every time that a BoxDecoration need to have `color: Colors.orange`.

Comment: just use global variable, you can specify final Color orangeColor = Colors.orange; for me i always create 1 file named globals.dart that contains all the global variable that i need and import it to every single file that need to use it

Answer (score 0):

You could do this many different ways. Setup a const BoxDecoration somewhere that you then use for decorating certain widgets and use the copyWith() to copy it's color while overriding anything else you add. Or you could use the Theme inherited widget.